# Aligning controls on a Visual Studio 2012 Windows Form?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I [am certain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1817547/969613) that <= Visual Studio 2010 contained options to align controls on a Windows Form, but on 2012 the controls on the Layout toolbar seem grayed out, why is this?

[image: Screenshot]

I really don't want to have to install just 2010 to center a control on my Windows Form, is there a way around this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

They seem to be just for **multiple** controls. 
I've tried it in VS 2010 also, same there.

For only one control, you can use **Format => Center in Form => Horizontally/Vertically**

In VS 2010, there are default menu buttons for the commands above, but not in VS 2012 by default. Maybe you've been confused with that. (for the certainty issue: it is for "groups of controls", as noted)

When you select multiple controls, these buttons will be available.

Answer (score 15):

Beytan Kurt's explanation is correct.  Also note that you can add the **Center Horizontally** and **Center Vertically** shortcuts to the toolbar manually, rather than using **Format > Center in Form**.

1. Right-click the toolbar
2. Click **Customize...**
3. Select the **Commands** tab
4. Select the **Toolbar** radio button and select **Layout** from the dropdown
5. Click **Add Command...** and select **Format** from the *Categories* section
6. Select the **Center Horizontally** and **Center Vertically** commands (not *Center Horizontal* and *Center Vertical*)

Comment: How intuitive. :facepalm:

Comment: Thanks!!  I have no idea why these aren't included by default???